# How to get Windows XP to snap windows to desktop like Vista?

Tags: windows-xp, desktop, window-manager

You can drag windows in Windows Vista to have them snap to the sides, and have the window only take up half the screen, etc. Is there software for XP that mimics this functionality?

Comment: There is no such functionality in Vista.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should check out [WinSplit Revolution](http://www.winsplit-revolution.com/), it has what you need and is customizable.

[image]

Comment: Worth mentioning - that software is free, with CC by-nc-nd 3.0 - so you can install it anywhere, but not put it on a disk and sell it.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [AquaSnap](http://www.nurgo-software.com/products/aquasnap) which imitates Windows 7 Aero Snap with added functionality and it only costs $9