# What program can I use to clip windows to other windows in XP?

Tags: windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get Windows XP to snap windows to desktop like Vista?](https://superuser.com/questions/154514/how-to-get-windows-xp-to-snap-windows-to-desktop-like-vista)

If I drag a window, i want it to "clip" to edges. I used to use a program for this, but forgot both the name and what to google for. Any ideas? Does Windows maybe allow this as standard now?

Comment: Upgrade to W7 :)

Comment: I just tried the AeroSNAP (i actually have Windows 7 it turns out) and unfortunately, it doesn't allow my Chrome browser to snap properly?

Comment: You need to explain the error as 'snap properly' is too vague. You may also want to make a new post if it works for other programs and just not Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're referring to?
http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/14238/add-windows-7s-aerosnap-feature-to-vista-and-xp/

If so you can download it here.
http://download.cnet.com/AeroSnap/3000-2072_4-10968506.html

Answer (score 0):

I've been using a small Windows application called [Sizer](http://www.brianapps.net/sizer) for several years. It has a "snap" feature that effectively does what you want, I think. Check it out, it's free.